# In git bash ..sign in with your browser..how to tackle.. suggest some way?

Tags: github, methods, push

In git bash sign in with your browser is shown I push the files in the repository it shown the same thing sign in wid your browser or else take a token ... suggest some way to tackle?

I want to push all my files in my repository but in the git push -u origin master ...it showed me the sign in with your browser..i already sign in again I push the files ...it showed the same thing